# Find the surface satisfying $\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2} = 6x+2$ and touching $z=x^3+y^3$ along its section by the plane $x+y+1=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I started off by staring to solve for the DE first:

as $$z=x^3+x^2+C(y)+D$$ where *C* is a function of *y* and *D* is an arbitrary constant of integration; and this is all I could do. Kindly provide any hints as to what it means '*touching (some surface) along its section (by a plane)*', as I am not able to proceed after this.

Comment: What it means is that plane $x+y+1 = 0$ intersects both surfaces at points where both surfaces touch each other (tangent).

Comment: Thanks @MathLover I think this hint is good enough!